# vscode use tab and shift tab for up and down in dropdown menu/quick open menus

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

When in drop down menus or quick open menus, by using keybindings like `ctrl+p` or `ctrl+shift+p`, how would I make it so `tab` and `shift+tab` go up/down the list?

Instead what happens when I use `tab`/`shift+tab`, is that it tabs across the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turns out to be trickier than I expected.

First, I couldn't get it to work with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> so you will see in the below that I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> instead.

Second, in order to get the typical behaviour of stopping on an item and NOT having it automatically selected and run I had to use a different sort of command for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> entry.

I suspect there is something hard-wired into the keybinding functionality of the quickOpen panels that is very hard to work around.  But try this out in your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "when": "inQuickOpen"
},

{
    "key": "ctrl+tab",
    // should work but runs the selection immediately
    // "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigatePrevious",
    "command": "list.focusUp",
    "when": "inQuickOpen"
}
```

Comment: For me `workbench.action.quickOpenNavigatePrevious` works fine and doesn't automatically select it. `list.focusUp` was the one that did nothing.

Comment: That's very weird??  I think somehow the `tab` key is interpreted as a completion command for me, but not for you.  Whenever I release the `ctrl` key it fires the selection. 
 Glad it works for you - and there are options for other people to try just incase.

Comment: Yea this is very weird. For some reason now, I'm having the same issue you described `quickOpenNavigatePrevious` now auto selects. I tried your solution (`list.focusUp`) and it started working, but later it stopped again. There was another problem with `list.focusUp` anyways, it's actually *focusing* on the item, so you can't type anymore, plus once you do `ctrl+tab`, then `tab` is useless again. Plus it's kind of slow. The solution I found was `workbench.action.quickOpenSelectPrevious`. The name kind of gives the suggestion that it will automatically select it, but it doesn't.